# Container is taking event of Button in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I have a grid container wchich consist two button.and i add this container in the form.
When i click on the  button  it is working fine but when i click outside the buttons then the event fired by those button which have the focus at that time.

```
GridFieldManager startStopButtonContainer = new GridFieldManager(2,Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
startStopButtonContainer.add(slideRestart);
startStopButtonContainer.add(slideStop);
add(startStopButtonContainer);
```

now i click on the slideRestart it works fine but when i click outside the button then also it is taking event.

Please help me out...:)

Comment: Are slideRestart and slideStop custom buttons?

Comment: yes these are custom buttons.I tried getfieldatlocation but it is not working

Comment: Are you overriding touchEvent()? If so make sure you return false when you aren't doing anything with the touch, otherwise the focus won't move

Answer (score 0):

Add nullfield at starting & ending at each row of the gridfieldManager.And set style Field.Non_FOCASABLE to that nullfields.And set the default focus at buttonfield.

Note: nullfields must cover the remaining part of gridfieldManager.

you can use

```
 LabelField field = new LabelField("   ",Field.NON_FOCUSABLE)
        {
            protected void layout(int width, int height) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.layout(width, height);
                setExtent((Display.getWidth()-(buttonField.getPreferredWidth()+buttonField.getPreferredWidth())/2, height);
            }
        };
```

as nullfield.